# Using Xcode 7 to develop apps for iOS 6 and iOS 7

Tags: ios, xcode

I'd like to use Xcode 7 when it's released to develop apps for i-devices running iOS 7 or even iOS 6. Is this possible? ... I know

- I'll need to use Objective-C; Swift code generally requires devices be running iOS 8 (or at least iOS 7).
- I know each version of iOS brings new capabilities (and code that is not backwards compatible).

I'm planning pretty basic apps (I'm very much a beginner), and I'm *assuming* apps are forward compatible, *e.g.,* if it runs OK on an iOS 6 iPhone 4S then it'll be OK on an iOS 8 iPhone 4s. What I don't know are settings, options, etc. I should set in the Xcode IDE to assure my code will compile and run on all OS's >=6 or 7. What, if anything, do I need to do when starting a project other than setting the Deployment Target to be iOS 6 or 7?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After you create the project in your target settings you need to choose deployment target 6.0

Then in your build setting you need to make sure you choose correct architectures that supports 32 bits and 64 bit processor.

If you are going to use storyboards you need to make sure that you dont rely on `Auto Layout` feature because that is ios 7 and later versions.

Comment: `Auto Layout` was introduced in iOS 6